# "She loves either me or John" vs "She either loves me or John"

Tags: grammar, usage

> 1) "She loves either me or John”
>   2) "She either loves me or John"

Are these two sentences interchangeable, or do I have to use the structure in "She either loves me or John" only in the sentences like "She either loves me or hates me"?

Answer (score 1):

Functionally, in your simple example, they are the same. However, there is a structural difference that may not be apparent.

If parsed and expanded, they become:

> 1. She loves either me or John.
>    She loves (me) or (John).
>    She loves me or she loves John.
> 2. She either loves me or John.
>    She (loves me) or (loves John).
>    She loves me or she loves John.

Everything is fine. You can use either construction for this sentence.

---

But consider what happens if she hates John.

Looking at the first construction:

> 1. She loves either me or hates John.
>    She loves (me) or (hates John).
>    She loves me or she loves hates John.

This is ungrammatical because *hates John* is not a meaningful object to which the verb *love* can apply.

However, the second construction still works:

> 2. She either loves me or hates John.
>    She (loves me) or (hates John).
>    She loves me or she hates John.

---

So, you have to be careful with where you place *either* in more complex sentences. Be sure that what comes after *either* is the same type of thing as what comes after *or*—and that both function as a phrase with what comes before *either*.